# How to open stubborn javascript links in a new tab or new window?

Tags: javascript, browser-tabs, hyperlink

Some websites use "creative" (javascript?) hyperlinks which break browser functionality, such as the ability to  ctrl+click or middle click links to open them in a new tab.

A common example, taleo HR websites
http://www.rogers.com/web/Careers.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=C_CP&_page=9

No matter what I try, I can only follow links by clicking on them normally; I can't open them in a new window. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Yes, href is set to # and JS is invoked on onclick event of links (site doesn't work with JS disabled). Perhaps there's some sort of browser plugin that can deal with this.

Comment: There is a request for a solution in Mozilla's Bugzilla: [Bug 55696 - "Force JavaScript link to open in new window or new tab"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=55696).

Comment: Yeah I always thought this is extremely silly

Comment: see also: https://superuser.com/questions/854797/why-does-ctrl-click-not-open-some-links-in-a-new-tab

Answer (score 3):

Your question is specific to Taleo, so my answer will be too :)

I've coded a UserScript that does what you want: it replaces all the JavaScript links with normal links, so you can just click them or open them in a new tab if you want.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Taleo Fix
// @namespace   https://github.com/raphaelh/taleo_fix
// @description Taleo Fix Links
// @include     http://*.taleo.net/*
// @include     https://*.taleo.net/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

function replaceLinks() {
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("titlelink");
    var url = window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + "jobdetail.ftl";

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].childNodes[0].href = url + "?job=" + rows[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
    }
}

if (typeof unsafeWindow.ftlPager_processResponse === 'function') {
    var _ftlPager_processResponse = unsafeWindow.ftlPager_processResponse;
    unsafeWindow.ftlPager_processResponse = function(f, b) {
        _ftlPager_processResponse(f, b);
        replaceLinks();
    };
}

if (typeof unsafeWindow.requisition_restoreDatesValues === 'function') {
    var _requisition_restoreDatesValues = unsafeWindow.requisition_restoreDatesValues;
    unsafeWindow.requisition_restoreDatesValues = function(d, b) {
        _requisition_restoreDatesValues(d, b);
        replaceLinks();
    };
}
```

You can find it here: https://github.com/raphaelh/taleo_fix/blob/master/Taleo_Fix.user.js

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can write your own scripts for [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (Firefox) or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) (Chrome)

For the example you mentioned, this Tampermonkey UserScript will set all JavaScript links in the search results to open in new tab / window (this depends on browser configuration, it's tabs for me).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       open links in tabs
// @match      http://rogers.taleo.net/careersection/technology/jobsearch.ftl*
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementById('ftlform').target="_blank"
```

Though you can write more generic versions of this, enabling this functionality for all JavaScript links without breaking other usability will be hard.

A middlepath could be to set an event handler for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, that will temporarily set the target for ALL forms to "_blank" as long as the key is held.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another userscript, which wraps any element with an `onclick="document.location='some_url'"` attribute in an `<a href=some_url>` element and removes the `onclick`.

I wrote it for a specific site, but it's generic enough that it may be useful to others. Don't forget to change the **@match** URL below.

This works when the links are loaded by an AJAX call, hence the MutationObserver.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         JavaScript link fixer
// @version      0.1
// @description  Change JavaScript links to open in new tab/window
// @author       EM0
// @match        http://WHATEVER-WEBSITE-YOU-WANT/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

var modifyLink = function(linkNode) {
    // Re-create the regex every time, otherwise its lastIndex needs to be reset
    var linkRegex = /document\.location\s*=\s*\'([^']+)\'/g;

    var onclickText = linkNode.getAttribute('onclick');
    if (!onclickText)
        return;

    var match = linkRegex.exec(onclickText);
    if (!match) {
        console.log('Failed to find URL in onclick text ' + onclickText);
        return;
    }

    var targetUrl = match[1];
    console.log('Modifying link with target URL ' + targetUrl);

    // Clear onclick, so it doesn't match the selector, before modifying the DOM
    linkNode.removeAttribute('onclick');

    // Wrap the original element in a new <a href='target_url' /> element
    var newLink = document.createElement('a');
    newLink.href = targetUrl;
    var parent = linkNode.parentNode;
    newLink.appendChild(linkNode);
    parent.appendChild(newLink);
};

var modifyLinks = function() {
    var onclickNodes = document.querySelectorAll('*[onclick]');
    [].forEach.call(onclickNodes, modifyLink);
};

var observeDOM = (function(){
    var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

    return function(obj, callback) {
        if (MutationObserver) {
            var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
                if (mutations[0].addedNodes.length || mutations[0].removedNodes.length)
                    callback();
            });

            obs.observe(obj, { childList:true, subtree:true });
        }
    };
})();


(function() {
    'use strict';
    observeDOM(document.body, modifyLinks);
})();
```