# Firefox: open new tab in background (i.e. do not switch to it) when pressing CMD

Tags: macos, firefox, tabbed-browsing

`Firefox 38.0.5` @ `OSX 10.10.3`.

I've noticed that with **some** links, Firefox will switch to the newly opened tab, regardless of its settings.

"When I open a link in a new tab, switch to it immediately" is off, "`browser.tabs.loadBookmarksInBackground`" is on.

- only happens if I `CMD`+`left click`, while if I `middle click` it works as expected
- occurs with a mailing list I receive, but if I copy the same html code of that mail in a clean html page, it doesn't happen any more
- didn't happen with Chrome
- those links have an image as content, and no text
- I access them through google inbox or gmail

How do I make it work properly even with `CMD`+`left click`?

Answer (score 0):

From: [Why does CTRL-click not open some links in a new tab?](https://superuser.com/questions/854797/why-does-ctrl-click-not-open-some-links-in-a-new-tab)

This applies to CMD + Click as well, despite just stating Ctrl + Click.

> Lets take this link as an example:
>
> ```
> <a href="test.php" onclick="someFunction(this); return false;">Test</a>
> ```
>
> The href attribute, in this case, is creating a pseudo link for
>   readability (it will also allow the link to work even if JavaScript is
>   disabled). The reason for this is because the onclick attribute always
>   runs first. Big sites like Google do this to track clicks and to try
>   to prevent a user from visiting malware sites. Because of this, for
>   some reason Ctrl + Click does not work. However, if you use the
>   middle-button on your mouse, that almost always works.