# On some websites, why doesn't Ctrl + Click work, but right-click > Open in new tab, does?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

On some websites <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + clicking links opens them in the same tab... grrrr! Yet right-clicking > `Open in new tab`, does work.

It's frustrating - is there any way to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click work on all websites? Why *doesn't* this work on the occasional website? I.e. what's the technical reason?

Comment: In my Firefox 38.0.5 and Chromium 41.0 on KDE 4.10 the page loads in the same tab as well as in the new tab if done via CTRL+Click. Silly actually! But, a pure middle-click works exactly as `right-click -> Open in new tab.`

Comment: Related: Similar question for Firefox: https://superuser.com/questions/854797/why-does-ctrl-click-not-open-some-links-in-a-new-tab/

Comment: I wrote a Chrome add-on that fixes this. https://github.com/danielnixon/link-fixer#installation

Comment: Don't use Ctrl+Click. Just do a Middle click

Comment: @phuclv You sound a bit like Steve Jobs when he said "You're holding it wrong"

Comment: Using the Tabloc extension (available on both chrome and firefox), solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 12):

It is because of JavaScript that captures your clicks and, because of that, interferes with your keyboard shortcuts. If you disable JavaScript then shortcuts should start to work again. You can test it by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Developer tools), then clicking Settings (gear icon) and enabling option `Disable JavaScript`.

Comment: If you disable javascript then you may lose the functionality of the site as well. The site OP mentioned doesn't show "Must read" in the right-pane if javascript is disabled. But yeah, the solution might help on other websites.

Answer (score 4):

Middle-clicking seems to work like a ctrl-click (as mentioned by Firelord in the comments).

Comment: any alternative for middle-clicking on laptops?

Comment: Another alternative is right-clicking and then selecting Open Link in New Tab. But that's not as convenient as ctrl-click.

Comment: @Dhruvil21_04 almost all touchpads can do that but [the setting depends on the type of touchpad](https://superuser.com/a/1645250/241386)