# How to open link in new tab without right-clicking?

Tags: firefox, hyperlink, right-click

Is there any way of opening a web link to a new tab without having to use the right-click function? I use Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

Simply hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> on a Mac) while clicking the link, or middle-click the link with your mouse.

(Middle-clicking = using the middle mouse button, which on most mice is the mouse wheel, which is clickable.)

Comment: i dont have a mouse, i use the touchpad on my laptop. How do i do it on touchpad?

Comment: The answer is already up there - hold the [Ctrl] key on your keyboard (or the [Cmd] key if using a Mac) while tapping (i.e. clicking) the link.

Comment: I regularly use ctrl-click to open links in new tabs, but I sometimes encounter websites where that still opens the link in the current tab.  Does anyone understand why that happens?  Does the problem likely originate in the HTML, CSS, or JS?

Comment: I found another post here that does a good job addressing the problem I described above, which I've opted to fix by installing the link-fixer browser plugin:  https://superuser.com/questions/854797/why-does-ctrl-click-not-open-some-links-in-a-new-tab