# Open any link in new tab

Tags: firefox, links

I want to be able to open any link in a new tab, but some websites [(example)](http://www.dictionary.com) work like this:

Whenever I click on a link, the link opens in the current tab so neither right-click, middle-click nor Ctrl+Click work.

Is there a way around this?

**EDIT2:** As you seem to mistake that ***only SOME, not ALL*** the links are regular, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lKod.gif) shows the behavior of the links on the site.

**EDIT:** Notice that not all of the links in the [example](http://www.dictionary.com) work like regular links. What I actually want to accomplish is to easily (a) compare the definitions of multiple words or (b) branch out and compare the definitions of multiple referenced words, but the individual links for words open in the same tab.

Comment: Interesting... I'm on a different browser & probably OS too, but first time I try one of those links it fails, 2nd attempt it does open a new tab. Also, right click/open in new tab [or window] works, even first time.

Comment: If I click a link and quickly hit Esc, the link works like normal.

Comment: The 1st click always fails for Windows 10 on Microsoft Edge, Firefox Quantum and Google Chrome.

Comment: Right click open in new tab works for me in FF

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm not clear enough; Not all of the links on that site work like regular links. An example is the links for individual words. I can't easily compare the definitions for multiple words because the links open in the same tab.

Comment: @KasperKnudsen So give an example of a page you are having problems with and which links on that page. We are not mind readers. [Edit] your question to include this vital information.

Comment: Every link on the home page works as expected. Right click to open in a new tab/window. Please be more explicit.

Comment: This is the fault of dictionary.com's developers. I wrote an add-on that will fix the ctrl+click issue. Won't help with right-click or middle-click though. https://github.com/danielnixon/link-fixer

Comment: Negative, this is not a duplicate because that context menu is not available.

Comment: Yes, it is duplicate because it describes the REASON why some sites do not allow the "open in new tab" behavior, however it is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that dictionary.com is using ReactJS. according to this [Why does CTRL-click not open some links in a new tab?](https://superuser.com/questions/854797/why-does-ctrl-click-not-open-some-links-in-a-new-tab) and google for reactjs not opening links in new tabs will probably give you more information as well.

as @DavidPostill♦ noted, right clicking and selecting "open link in new tab" works well...

I also noted that your example site manipulates the history, so going to the site, clicking on a few links, and going back to the startpage is not possible.

If right clicking and choosing "open in new tab" is not acceptable, then you may be able to use a macro (if your keyboard/mouse or a third party plugin for windows) supports it