# How to open JavaScript link in new tab

Tags: firefox, browser, javascript, browser-tabs

I’m stuck using a crappy website that is very dynamic and uses a lot of JavaScript, basically it has a table with many rows, each containing a link. Initially the rows are in a very poor order and I click various buttons to sort them. However, when I click a link and then try to go back to this page, when I go back the ordering is back to its useless initial state.

To overcome this problem I would like to open links in new tabs. But since the links have the location `javascript:void(0)` how can I do this? If I try click with the middle button of the mouse, a new empty tab opens. I’m using Firefox and am willing to install addons.

Here’s [a link](http://www71.zippyshare.com/v/EKDS1k3z/file.html) to a download of the source code.

Comment: what website are you refering to ?

Comment: @niceman it's not public, would you like me to tell you a certain detail?

Comment: well what do you mean by "it doesn't go back to where I want it" ? what do you want ?

Comment: The previous page contains many links which are initially sorted in an order not useful to me. After clicking some buttons (e.g. sort by date etc.) then the list becomes useful. However, when I click on one of the links and leave the page and then go back to it, the list is in the initial useless order.

Comment: hmmm, this is a problem with the website itself(they didn't program it well)

Comment: could you post the source of it in a link ?

Comment: @niceman sorry, I don't understand what you're asking? The entire website is private and not available to the public (though I don't mind posting info about it or the pages source code)

Comment: post the page source code you're having problems with.

Comment: @niceman http://www71.zippyshare.com/v/EKDS1k3z/file.html

Comment: Similar to http://superuser.com/questions/604705/how-to-open-stubborn-javascript-links-in-a-new-tab-or-new-window

Answer (score 1):

There was once an add-on called "Smart Middle Click" that provided the ability to middle-click JavaScript links. It's no longer available at addons.mozilla.org or the author's website, but I've uploaded a copy for you:

http://www67.zippyshare.com/v/7SsmjES2/file.html

SMC doesn't work with all JS links, but rarely has trouble with the type you described. Hope it does the job for you!

Comment: How do you use the add on?

Comment: Install add-on, middle-click a JavaScript link. It'll either work or it won't.

Comment: dang it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Since Smart Middle Click didn't work for you, try this:

- Open the Developer Console (Ctrl+Shift+K)
- Click one of your links
- Quickly hit Esc (or the Stop button) before the page changes
- Middle-click the resulting link in the Console

It's a significantly less convenient solution, but it beats what you're doing now, and unfortunately, short of writing your own add-on or Greasemonkey script, it's your last remaining option.