# How to open javascript links in a new tab using tampermonkey / greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I use a website for work which employs frustrating JavaScript links. The following post offers a solution:

[How to open stubborn javascript links in a new tab or new window?](https://superuser.com/questions/604705/how-to-open-stubborn-javascript-links-in-a-new-tab-or-new-window)

However, I haven't been able to amend the scripts offered to work for the site I'm using. Details below....

http://www.nmswebquote.co.uk/fmc/default.aspx (no public access)

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$cphBaseContent$CPH_Section2$grdDetail','VIEW_ESTIMATE$6')

javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$cphBaseContent$CPH_Section2$grdDetail','ESTIMATE_HISTORY$6')
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: `__doPostBack` actually submits a form. Depending on lots of stuff, you can sometimes replace the form `POST` with `GET` links.  Or you can set the corresponding form to `target="_blank"`.  We would need to see the form HTML, *at a minimum*, to help you more.  Also, in Firefox, but not Chrome, you could do a generic rewrite of `__doPostBack()`, but I don't feel like messing with that approach right now.

Comment: @BrockAdams - The website has just been updated and the pesky javascript links are no longer in use. Thanks for your help anyhow.

Comment: That's good news.  Sorry I didn't get back to this question, but we are all free volunteers and RL has been taxing (literally).

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on this question 7 years later trying to do something similar, and Brock Adams' comment led me to an answer.

`__doPostBack` seems to be an ASP thing, so there's a form at the top of the page that looks like this:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="./foo.aspx" id="aspnetForm" role="presentation">
```

Adding `target="_blank"` causes all the links to open in new tabs.